# Have Eclipse show multiple tab rows?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

Was wondering if anyone know of a plugin or some sort to have Eclipse show rows of tabs. It would be really helpful in Android Application Development for this feature because you could have the .xml tabs Directly under your java classes. If you could imagine that.

If not perhaps some insight on possibly making it a plugin?

Note - Having multiple editor windows is nice but the windows boarder tends to get in the way....

Comment: Have you tried drag and drop before the xml tab below the Java code tab?

Comment: Yes i have, doesn't work. a perfect example of the tab display i'm trying to get would be how Frys.com shows there tabs at the top. There's rows.

Comment: Ok now I understand what you mean. An image would help in this case.